# Moving objects on a tilemap

Tags: java, android, scene

I'm stuck in a bad position. I'm trying to make a game that has 2 layers, the top layer (player) and the bottom layer(background,planets,enemies,ect). I'm using the e3roid engine for android, and when I move the bottom layer it seems to be like if you try to tap the screen you must be in the bottom layer to press an object. Its a bit like this diagram
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: "you must be in the bottom layer" doesn't make a lot of sense.  Do you mean that, after your app scrolls the bottom layer, it stops responding correctly to clicks that appear to be on top-layer sprites?

Comment: Or if it's a bottom-layer object that's no longer responsive after a scroll, how did you adjust your apps understanding of the object's location?  I haven't used e3roid, but unless you're doing something crazy you must have an internal coordinate system in your model of the game.

Comment: Like the object is outside the bottom layer it becomes unresponsive. There is no way to make the layers bigger though.